# Consistent Hash Function in Java

Tags: java, hash

I am working on project where we are implementing horizontal scaling of database. 
We are planing to split the data into three different database instances based on MacAddress from users data.

For Example:

User 1 - should go to DB1
 User 2 - should go to DB2
 User 3 - should go to DB3

If User1 comes again it has to go to DB1.
If User3 comes again it has to go to DB3.

For this requirement i need a hashing algorithm which should produce consistent has value based on the i need to distribute the users into different database.

I need provide the Mac Address as input for that hash algorithm and it should find out the db instance accordingly.

Could you please suggest some idea's or example programs..Thanks

Comment: You seem to have posted an excellent summary there of what you need to do!  What have you tried?  Where, specifically, are you stuck?

Comment: There are dozens of possibilities. You could just use `sum(mac) % 3`. That would be fast and consistent. The main problem you'll have to face is an even distribution across the servers.

Comment: I am looking for an various options to implement this changes. I need an example or sample implementation for consistent hash generation technique in java,

Comment: Also main think here is same hash value should be generated..For example if mac address as E2:22:22:2F:93:D3 given to the hash function..then at every time it has to generate the same hash value ..so that i can look/insert that data into corresponding DB instance..